# camera roll not opening when add UIImagePickerController as a sub view instead of Modal View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

[image]

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]
                                                 init];


    pickerController.view.frame=_vw1.frame;

    pickerController.delegate = self;
   // [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:NO completion:nil];


    [_vw1 addSubview:pickerController.view];
    //[pickerController viewWillAppear:YES]; // trickery to make it show
    [pickerController viewDidAppear:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Right. You can't do that. See the UIImagePickerController class reference. It tells you the **only** ways you can present an Image picker. Other ways like trying to imbed the picker's view in another view will not work.

Note that you need to do things differently on iPad vs iPhone/iPod.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class) you cannot add it as a subview, you should present it as a new controller

Here a piece of the doc:

> On iPhone or iPod touch, do this modally (full-screen) by calling the
>   presentViewController:animated:completion: method of the currently
>   active view controller, passing your configured image picker
>   controller as the new view controller.

Hope this helpes!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the camera as a subview, you can use AVFoundation. If you want step by step please reply so I don't write it here for waste!
Happy coding!